# Css Alignment Issue Angular Flexbox

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I have a following HTML with Angular FlexLayout in it

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
        <span >
         3123131
          </span>
        <span >
         1231231
          </span>

        <span >
           6568
          </span>
        <span >
           989
          </span>
    </div>
    <div fxLayoutGap="30px" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
        <div class="  line first"></div>
        <div class="  line red"></div>
        <div class="  line first"></div>
        <div class="  line red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around" fxLayoutGap="20px"
    style="border: 1px solid #eee; border-left: none; border-right: none; margin-left: 10px; padding: 10px;">
    <span class=" large" style="text-align: left;">
          12<span class="small" style="vertical-align: top;">%</span></span>
    <span class=" large" style="text-align: right;">
         68<span class="small" style="vertical-align: top;">%</span></span>
    <span class=" large" style="text-align: left;">
        45<span class="small" style="vertical-align: top;">%</span></span>
    <span class=" large" style="text-align: right;">
          35<span class="small" style="vertical-align: top;">%</span></span>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <div fxLayoutGap="30px" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
        <i class="icon thick"></i>
        <i class="icon thick"></i>
        <i class="icon thick"></i>
        <i class="icon thick"></i>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
        <span class=" " style="text-align: right;">
            684
          </span>
        <span class=" ">
            3514
          </span>
        <span class=" ">
           21
          </span>
        <span class=" ">
           354
          </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output of this is as below,

[image]

But I want them to be evenly aligned in the same straight line, I can't figure out what mistake I'm making in this

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pugsd)**

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly aligned in the same straight line"? Which elements are not properly aligned?

Comment: hello @ConnorsFan I want all 4 items in the first column to be center aligned!

Comment: Does that include "3123131"? Which item should be used as a reference to align the other items?

Comment: we can actually use `12%` as reference @ConnorsFan

Comment: And what about "3123131"? Should it be aligned in the same column?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes they all should be in one straight line `center` aligned to the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make horizontal alignment easier, you can define each item as having no width and a centered content. That can be achieved with an `inline-flex` container:

```css
.centered {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 0px;
}
```

After setting the `centered` class on the items to align, make sure that you use the same spacing on all lines (either `space-around` or `space-between`). [This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-soygvj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) shows what it looks like when `space-around` is used:

```html
<div fxLayout="column">
  <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
    <span class="centered">3123131</span>
    <span class="centered">1231231</span>
    <span class="centered">6568</span>
    <span class="centered">989</span>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
    <div class="centered line first"></div>
    <div class="centered line red"></div>
    <div class="centered line first"></div>
    <div class="centered line red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around" class="percentContainer">
  <span class="centered large">12<span class="percent">%</span></span>
  <span class="centered large">68<span class="percent">%</span></span>
  <span class="centered large">45<span class="percent">%</span></span>
  <span class="centered large">35<span class="percent">%</span></span>
</div>
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
    <i class="centered icon thick"></i>
    <i class="centered icon thick"></i>
    <i class="centered icon thick"></i>
    <i class="centered icon thick"></i>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
    <span class="centered">684</span>
    <span class="centered">3514</span>
    <span class="centered">21</span>
    <span class="centered">354</span>
  </div>
</div>
```